# iPhone Mail app "Load More Messages..."

Tags: iphone, email, uitableview, button

At the bottom of the tableview (list of emails), there is a button (?) called "Load More Messages...", is that a button created in the tableview cell or a button created as part of the footerview of the tableview. either way, how could I do the similar thing in my tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Button in your tableFooterView

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = yourButtonView;
self.tableView.tableFooterView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second section for that with just a single cell.